# How to make Generic Route in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How can I make a router like this

```
Route::any("/{controller}/{method}/{param}", "$controller@$method");
```

So that instead of specifing every single method in the routes file, I would be able to define a route for most cases for the convention http://example.com/controller/method/param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel 4.2 you can use [implicit controller][1].

> Laravel allows you to easily define a single route to handle every action in a controller. First, define the route using the Route::controller method:

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

> The controller method accepts two arguments. The first is the base URI the controller handles, while the second is the class name of the controller. Next, just add methods to your controller, prefixed with the HTTP verb they respond to:

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        //
    }

    public function postProfile()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#implicit-controllers

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
Route::any('{controller}/{method}/{param}', function ($controller, $method, $param) {
        return call_user_func_array($controller.'::'.$method, $param);
    });
```

Comment: sounds interesting, I come from MVC.NET and I am used to have a single route that looks like this, I have not tested your solution though, I will try it later today. @Avik question, how to handle different http methods?